# Reversing a Link List in JavaScript overwrites this.head and doesn't update

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Not sure what is going wrong here in the function reverseLinkedList.

I'm trying to reverse a Link List and the steps I've taken seems to work at online judges like leetcode/hackerrank. Ofcourse the default structure is different when creating the Link List.

```
class Node{
  ...
}


class LinkedList{
  constructor(){
    this.head = null;
    this.size = 0;
  };
    
  insert(data){
    this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
    this.size++;
  };

  printElements(){
    let current = this.head;
    while(current){
      console.log(current.data)
      current = current.next;
    }
  };

  reverseLinkedList(){
    let prev = null;
    let current = this.head;
    let temp;
    while(current){
        temp = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = temp;
    }
  }
}

const ll = new LinkedList();

ll.insert(1);
ll.insert(12);
ll.insert(6);

ll.reverseLinkedList();

ll.printElements();
```

Tried solving the same problem via leetcode/hackerrank and that works fine. I'm not sure why this is happening btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to set the new `.head` to the former last node:

```
reverseLinkedList() {
  let prev = null;
  let current = this.head;
  while (current) {
    const temp = current.next;
    current.next = prev;
    prev = current;
    current = temp;
  }
  this.head = prev;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end your head should point to prev so when you iterate linked list it start form prev (as new head ) add the below code when loop ended.

```
this.head = prev;
```